# Align text to bottom left of page in the same Div as a Centred full height photo

Tags: html, css, scroll

I’m trying to place text in the bottom left corner of a div and window, however It is not playing nice with a full height centered photo in the same section.

Here is the [Code pen](http://codepen.io/wordfa/pen/yJGErR).

```css
.full {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.name {
    position: absolute;
    text-decoration: none;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 40px;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, "Franklin Gothic Bold", "Arial Black", sans-serif;
    color: black;
    width: 960px;
}
.box {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vh;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="fullpage" class="inner">
    <div class="box">
        <img src="img/6.png" class="full animated slideInUp">
        <a class="name" href="http//:www.fredwordie.com">Fred Wordie</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

what I want:

[image]

Comment: Not really understand your problem, you want text outside the image?

Comment: yes, just added a photo

Comment: I provide a answer below , you may have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure whether match what you want 
,here is a codepen:
http://codepen.io/Carr1005/pen/LkrAab

no title overlay problem

revised on these two block :

```
.full {
   display:block;
   margin:auto;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100vh;
   background:yellow;
}

.box {
   display:block;
   margin:auto;
   height: 100vh;
   max-width:100%;
   position:relative;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this is not what i was looking for, The text is title for each image, but should be in the bottom left corner of the page, rather then in the bottom left corner of the image. So what ever the width of the image or window size, the name is always in the bottom left corner of the window. I hope that makes more sense.

Comment: uhh...doesn't  #fullpage  block mean page ?

Comment: yes, correct. that is the container for all these divs. however, the text is still not in the bottom left of the window.

Comment: that works for the first Div, but as you scroll down the names just stack up over each other. like so http://imgur.com/a/q1TSz

Comment: Just found out and revised , take a look

Comment: Thanks so much, i think you cracked it, what did you change?

Comment: In beginning I wanna let **#fullpage** keep postition:relative ,then **.name** 's position:absolute would affect by this , but   **#fullpage**  's  height won't strech when you scroll down , so every title stack up over each other , just let .box keep remain  postition:relative  but let its width be 100% not 100hv , and let **.full** 's width be 100hv which you use to locate image ~

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `.full` to `position: relative` and remove the `position` from `.box`

[code pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xOmzZV)

Comment: This is the desired result for the first Section, however, when more divs are added the names just overlay each other. How can I achieve that placement, relative to each added div?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.box-wrap{ position:relative;}
.name {
  position: absolute;
  text-decoration: none;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 0px;
  
  font-size: 36px;
  font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, "Franklin Gothic Bold", "Arial Black", sans-serif;
  color: black;
}

.box {
  margin: auto;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vh;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow
}

. body {
  margin: 0;
}

.my_popup_open {
  float: right;
}

.inner {
  overflow: none;
}

.top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
}

.icon {
  margin: 10px;
  max-height: 50px;
  max-width: 50px;
  float: right;
  -webkit-filter: invert(100%);
  -o-filter: invert(100%);
  -moz-filter: invert(100%);
  -ms-filter: invert(100%);
  filter: invert(100%);
}

.invert {
  -webkit-filter: invert(0%);
  -o-filter: invert(0%);
  -moz-filter: invert(0%);
  -ms-filter: invert(0%);
  filter: invert(0%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="fullpage" class="inner ">
  <div class="box-wrap">
    <div class="box">
      <img src="img/6.png" class="full animated slideInUp">

      
    </div>
    <a class="name" href="http//:www.fredwordie.com">Fred Wordie</a>
  </div>

  <div class="box-wrap">
    <div class="box"> <img src="img/3.png" class="full animated slideInUp"></div>
     <a class="name" href="http//:www.fredwordie.com">Fred Wordie</a> 
  </div>
  <div class="box-wrap">
    <div class="box"> <img src="img/6.png" class="full animated slideInUp">  </div>
    <a class="name" href="http//:www.fredwordie.com">Fred Wordie</a>
  </div>
  <div class="box-wrap">
    <div class="box"> <img src="img/3.png" class="full animated slideInUp"> </div>
     <a class="name" href="http//:www.fredwordie.com">Fred Wordie</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

check this out. I have wrapped the box in a wrapper named box-wrap and took a tag out from box and placed inside box-wrap.